# How to use two different custom dimension with BigQuery Legacy SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to build a query with legacy SQL where I need to use two distinct custom dimension. Here is what I've written until now :

```
SELECT
  count_distinct(hits.customDimensions.value) AS Articles,
  DATE(timestamp(hits.customDimensions.value)) AS date_, 
FROM
  [storied-toolbox-113108:112162023.ga_sessions_20161104]
WHERE
 hits.customDimensions.index=4 AND
 DATE(timestamp(hits.customDimensions.value)) > DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), -7, "DAY"))
GROUP BY
  date_
```

however I would like to apply `count_distinct` function on the customDimensions index 10 and apply `date` function on the customDimensions index 4.

How can I do this ?

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by splitting your SELECT statement into two:

```
SELECT count_distinct(hits.customDimensions.value) AS Articles
FROM [storied-toolbox-113108:112162023.ga_sessions_20161104]
WHERE hits.customDimensions.index=10

DATE(timestamp(hits.customDimensions.value)) AS date_
FROM [storied-toolbox-113108:112162023.ga_sessions_20161104]
WHERE hits.customDimensions.index=4 AND
DATE(timestamp(hits.customDimensions.value)) > DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), -7, "DAY"))
```

Then you can union the results into two separate columns:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...), (SELECT ...)
```

or a single one (needs to be of the same type though, hence string cast)

```
SELECT COALESCE(date_, Articles)
FROM (SELECT STRING(...) as date_ ...)
, (SELECT STRING(...) as Articles ...)
```

Comment: actually it's not working. got the number of articles but date is returned as null and got the date but articles are returned as null...

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```sql
SELECT date,
  (IF(hits.customDimensions.index=3,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)),
  (IF(hits.customDimensions.index=9,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL))
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
  [YourTable.ga_sessions_], 
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, 'DAY'), 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
LIMIT 1000
```